# Some variables not being passed by reference

Tags: php

Yesterday a friend of mine and I were walking through static classes, and instanced ones; then suddenly some weird behavior occurred.

```
<?php
class NumberContainerO {
     public $_number;

     public function __construct($number) {
          $this->_number = $number;
     }    
}

$list = array();

$n = new NumberContainerO(1);
$list[] = &$n->_number;

$n = new NumberContainerO(2);
$list[] = &$n->_number;

$n = new NumberContainerO(3);
$list[] = &$n->_number;

var_dump($list);
?>

<?php
class NumberContainer {
     public static $_number;

     public static function __Add($number) {
          self::$_number = $number;
     }
}

$list = array();

NumberContainer::__Add(1);
$list[] = &NumberContainer::$_number;

NumberContainer::__Add(2);
$list[] = &NumberContainer::$_number;

NumberContainer::__Add(3);
$list[] = &NumberContainer::$_number;

var_dump($list);
?>
```

Output

> array(3) {
>     [0]=>
>     int(1)
>     [1]=>
>     int(2)
>     [2]=>
>     &int(3)
>   }
>   array(3) {
>     [0]=>
>     &int(3)
>     [1]=>
>     &int(3)
>     [2]=>
>     &int(3)
>   }

Why is int(1), and int(2) not passed by reference?

Codepad: http://codepad.org/DsEZDFYf

Comment: @MichaelRushton There are two var dumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Unsetting References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php).

When you do `$n = new NumberContainerO(2);` (and `$n = new NumberContainerO(3);`) you're unsetting the previous `$n->_number`, destroying the reference. The array element then just becomes your standard non-referenced value.